# can i apply mysql partition on this table?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `thread_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `forum_id` tinyint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message` mediumtext collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `thread_id` (`thread_id`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `forum_id` (`forum_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3273548 ;
```

how can i apply partition on it and what is the best type of partition i can use ?

Query is

`SELECT id,user_id,message FROM posts WHERE thread_id = %`

with some joins

PS: table is 2.5 GiB

- don't know much about MySQL partition :(

thank you

Comment: partition how? are you using mysql 5.5? do you want to implement your *own* sharding schema?

Comment: we did updgrade from 5.0 to 5.1, and 5.1 does have partition, but we don't know how to apply it, thanks

Comment: in that case I would try to detect the highest entity and partition with that

Answer (score 0):

from the top of my head (without knowing much about your application) I would assume that your highest entity its "forum" I would do a sharding per "forum".

Remember [sharding isn't easy](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/08/06/why-you-dont-want-to-shard/)

### Edit 1

First: 2.5gb of data size isn't much, we work with tables much more big than that.

tips:

- check your indexes
- move form MyISAM to InnoDB -> this
  will make the queries a little more
  slow but not blocking.
- before shard try to [denormalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization)

Comment: we did convert the table from MyISAM to InnoDB, but after a while we run't into a problem, corrupted tables or information in files .myi & frm ( after restaring mysql server ), we couldn't fix it that way we had to restore a backup and go back to MyISAM

Comment: back to InnoDB again: the performance change will be big. There are many techniques to change the schema change with a big table without downtimes.